# Pop up every checkboxes on click using html, css, and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help on how to have a pop up in every checkboxes of yes and no..
I need these html codes to have a pop up on every checkboxes on them..

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="display: inline-flex;">
     <p>1. Do You Have a Written Mission Statement?</p>                         
     <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="boolean" value="Yes">
     <label for="yes"></label>Yes</label>  
     <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="boolean" value="No">
     <label for="no">No</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="display:inline-flex;"> 
     <p>2. Do You Have a Written Vision Statement?</p>
     <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="boolean" value="Yes">
     <label for="yes">Yes</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="boolean" value="No">
     <label for="no">No</label>
     </div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="display:inline-flex;"> 
     <p>3. Do You Have a Logo?</p>
     <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="boolean" value="Yes">
     <label for="yes">Yes</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="boolean" value="No">
     <label for="no">No</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="display:inline-flex;"> 
     <p>4. Do You Have a strategic Position?</p>
     <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="boolean" value="Yes">
     <label for="yes">Yes</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="boolean" value="No">
     <label for="no">No</label>
</div>
```

Every checkboxes on them needs to have a pop up

Comment: You can't use the same ```id``` on all those inputs.

Comment: What should pop up and when?

Comment: Something like a comments
for example by clicking yes the pop up will show: 
Good! Having a mission statement is important for setting direction of your business.

and by clicking no:
Having a mission statement is important for setting direction of your business. All efforts should be ...

and for the others as well are another comments or definitions

Comment: @battaboombattabaam Is there a way to show the pop up in the center of the screen? An editable alert message or maybe a modal box in every checkboxes once clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function validateCheck(check, message) {
            if (check.checked) {
                dialog.show();
                var x = document.getElementById("content");
                x.innerHTML = message
            } else {
                dialog.close();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #dialog {
            position: fixed;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 7px;
            width: 300px;
            z-index: 10;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: fixed
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="display: inline-flex;">
        <p>1. Do You Have a Written Mission Statement?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="boolean" value="Yes" onchange="validateCheck(this,'Good choice')" />
        <label for="yes"></label>Yes</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="boolean" value="No" onchange="validateCheck(this,'Bad choice');" />
        <label for="no">No</label>
    </div>
    <dialog id="dialog">
        <form method="dialog">
            <h2>Definition</h2>
            <p id="content"></p>
            <menu>
                <button id="confirmBtn" value="default">OK</button>
            </menu>
        </form>
    </dialog>

</body>

</html>
```

Try this

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function validateCheck(check, message) {
            if (check.checked) {
                alert(message)
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="display: inline-flex;">
        <p>1. Do You Have a Written Mission Statement?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="boolean" value="Yes" onchange="validateCheck(this,'Good choice')" />
        <label for="yes"></label>Yes</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="boolean" value="No" onchange="validateCheck(this,'Bad choice');" />
        <label for="no">No</label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is great! But how to clear the "This Page Say"? and fix it's alignment in center?

Comment: Can you please share what exactly is needed?? Clear thus page as in?

Comment: Okay here's the thing.. When I click Yes a pop up(a comment or a paragraph) will appear in the middle of the screen and the same for No a pop up will also appear..

Comment: The pop up is already good but it shows at the top of the screen. it needs to be in the center. Is there a way for it to be in the middle?

Comment: any reason why u want to build a custom alert?? i have updated the snippet to use HTML dialogs

Comment: The reason is to show the dialogue box as a definition of the question when they click the checkbox in either yes and no. If they click yes they will get a good definition, and if they click no they will get an advice definition..

Comment: I've tried your code and it was okay at your snippet but on my end it become messy. When I click the checkbox the pop up shows but the ok button won't work so I tried to uncheck the checkbox the pop up closes itself.. It might be my codes is the problem but I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have search a custom alert to customize the alert box and here's the code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#dialogoverlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border-radius:7px; 
    width:550px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background:#333; padding:20px; color:#FFF; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ background: #666; padding:10px; text-align:right; }
</style>
<script>
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Definition";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
    }
    this.ok = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="display: inline-flex;">
                            <p>1. Do You Have a Written Mission Statement?</p>                         
                            <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="boolean" value="Yes" onclick="Alert.render('Good Choice!')">
                            <label for="yes">Yes</label>  
                            <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="boolean" value="No" onclick="Alert.render('Too bad :c')">
                            <label for="no">No</label>
                            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Well this looks quite good now so thanks guys for helping me learn ^_^

Comment: I don't know how to make the dialogue box aligned on the center, anyone knows?